# Not able to instantiate a new contract from factory contract on geth console on private network

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, remix

Please let me how do I actually instantiate a new contract from factory on geth console. I am not able to instantiate from the geth console.
The Factory Contract's createFactory shown below worked perfectly fine when I try calling it from Remix browser online. It also increments the count by 1 each time it gets called. My Miner is up and running when I do all this stuff.

Below is the source code .I compile the source using Remix online browser solidity compiler

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Factory {

    bytes32[] Names;
    address[] newContracts;
    uint public count=0;

    function createContract (bytes32 name) {
        address newContract = new Contract(name);
        count=count+1;
        newContracts.push(newContract);
    } 

    function getName  (uint i) constant returns (address sblcAddress){
        Contract con = Contract(newContracts[i]);
      sblcAddress= address(con);
       return sblcAddress;
    }
}

contract Contract {

    bytes32 public Name;

    function Contract (bytes32 name) {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

After opening the geth console and unlocking my base account I deploy the below code.

```
var browser_contractfactory_sol_factoryContract = web3.eth.contract([{"constant":true,"inputs":[],"name":"count","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"name","type":"bytes32"}],"name":"createContract","outputs":[],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"i","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getName","outputs":[{"name":"sblcAddress","type":"address"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"}]);
var browser_contractfactory_sol_factory = browser_contractfactory_sol_factoryContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '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', 
     gas: '1087718887660'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 });
```

The above code creates a new factory contract at a new address .I get the address where my Factory contract is created. Using that address I try to access the createContract function of Factory contract

```
var factoryCInstance = browser_contractfactory_sol_factoryContract.at('0x...FactoryContractAddress..');


factoryCInstance.createContract(3,{from: web3.eth.accounts[0]});
```

After running the above line all I get is the transaction hash.
When I call  `factoryCInstance.count();` The count displayed is 0

Comment: @Rob Hitchens, Your help would be appreciated. My miner is up. I wait for a couple of minutes before calling the count() function. Everything works fine when I do it via remix but the createContract function does not work when I do it on geth console.

Comment: Can you check the receipt of the transaction that calls `createContract`? If the transaction failed it will not update the state variables.

Comment: This is the transaction receipt when I call createContract                          
 {
  blockHash: "0xe71764eb35304f6a35b58b7b7dee8d94610e929a05ab2bcdc4371c0b2509640a",
  blockNumber: 3236,
  contractAddress: null,
  cumulativeGasUsed: 90000,
  from: "0x.. Eth Base Account address",
  gasUsed: 90000,
  logs: [],
  logsBloom: "0x000...000",
  root: "0xf661019257bb8522ad073c82ea244c43f6845e86f2b253388d28f714884cc7c8",
  to: "0xAccountAddress of Factory Contract",
  transactionHash: "0x5f64ea44e7e3b7658d8c99a08d5e06b5deb31fa595930aa8f4c6864d45
ce7825",
  transactionIndex: 0
}

Comment: @Ismael The blockhash and numbers are shown in the transaction receipt. Also on doing eth.pendingTransactions I get []  nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling the createContract() with the gas value specified solved my issue

factoryCInstance.createContract(2,{from:eth.accounts[0],gas: 470000});